# Refresh jQuery dataTable which is using pipeline function

Tags: jquery, datatable, pipeline

I am having trouble refreshing data on datatables. I'm using the [datatable pipeline example](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html) from datatable, due to large amounts of data. But I can't  find a way to force a refresh after data modification (using a form, from a bootstrap dialogue).

how can I force a refresh of pipeline?

Without pipeline, `oTable.api().ajax.reload()` works perfectly. But I don't understand how I can do the same using the function here:

```
// Pipelining function for DataTables. To be used to the 'ajax' option of DataTables

$.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
    // Configuration options
    var conf = $.extend( {
        pages: 5,     // number of pages to cache
        url: '',      // script url
        data: null,   // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                      // matching how `ajax.data` works in DataTables
        method: 'GET' // Ajax HTTP method
    }, opts );

    // Private variables for storing the cache
    var cacheLower = -1;
    var cacheUpper = null;
    var cacheLastRequest = null;
    var cacheLastJson = null;

    return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
        var ajax          = false;
        var requestStart  = request.start;
        var drawStart     = request.start;
        var requestLength = request.length;
        var requestEnd    = requestStart + requestLength;

        if ( settings.clearCache ) {
            // API requested that the cache be cleared
            ajax = true;
            settings.clearCache = false;
        }
        else if ( cacheLower < 0 || requestStart < cacheLower || requestEnd > cacheUpper ) {
            // outside cached data - need to make a request
            ajax = true;
        }
        else if ( JSON.stringify( request.order )   !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.order ) ||
                  JSON.stringify( request.columns ) !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.columns ) ||
                  JSON.stringify( request.search )  !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.search )
        ) {
            // properties changed (ordering, columns, searching)
            ajax = true;
        }

        // Store the request for checking next time around
        cacheLastRequest = $.extend( true, {}, request );

        if ( ajax ) {
            // Need data from the server
            if ( requestStart < cacheLower ) {
                requestStart = requestStart - (requestLength*(conf.pages-1));

                if ( requestStart < 0 ) {
                    requestStart = 0;
                }
            }

            cacheLower = requestStart;
            cacheUpper = requestStart + (requestLength * conf.pages);

            request.start = requestStart;
            request.length = requestLength*conf.pages;

            // Provide the same `data` options as DataTables.
            if ( $.isFunction ( conf.data ) ) {
                // As a function it is executed with the data object as an arg
                // for manipulation. If an object is returned, it is used as the
                // data object to submit
                var d = conf.data( request );
                if ( d ) {
                    $.extend( request, d );
                }
            }
            else if ( $.isPlainObject( conf.data ) ) {
                // As an object, the data given extends the default
                $.extend( request, conf.data );
            }

            settings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                "type":     conf.method,
                "url":      conf.url,
                "data":     request,
                "dataType": "json",
                "cache":    false,
                "success":  function ( json ) {
                    cacheLastJson = $.extend(true, {}, json);

                    if ( cacheLower != drawStart ) {
                        json.data.splice( 0, drawStart-cacheLower );
                    }
                    json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );

                    drawCallback( json );
                }
            } );
        }
        else {
            json = $.extend( true, {}, cacheLastJson );
            json.draw = request.draw; // Update the echo for each response
            json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
            json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );

            drawCallback(json);
        }
    }
};

// Register an API method that will empty the pipelined data, forcing an Ajax
// fetch on the next draw (i.e. `table.clearPipeline().draw()`)
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'clearPipeline()', function () {
    return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
        settings.clearCache = true;
    } );
} );


//
// DataTables initialisation
//
$(document).ready(function() {

    oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
            url: 'scripts/server_processing.php',
            pages: 5 // number of pages to cache
        } )
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allan (datatables's author) answer this question on [his forum](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/86926#Comment_86926) :

> [The pipeline example code](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html) actually registers a plug-in API method
>   which provides the ability to clear the pipeline - you could use it
>   thus:
>
> ```
> table.clearPipeline().draw();
> ```
>
> i.e. clear and then reload.

in my case I used this syntax to make it work :

```
$('table.dataTable').DataTable().clearPipeline().draw();
```

Comment: But where in javascript code I have to insert this line, if my table with id="example" - $('#example) ?? Thank you